Narrowing a variable v of generic type T to ensure the type of v[key] for a specific key
Given a variable v of generic type T extends { a: string }, how can we narrow it so that v['count'] is typed as number AND we can call setProperty(v, 'count', 1) ?
function maybeSetCountToOne<T extends {a: string}>(v: T) {
    if ('count' in v && typeof (v.count) === 'number') {
        v.count = 1 // works (but v.count is unknown)
        setProperty(v, 'count', 1) // fails because 'T["count"]' could be unrelated to 'number'
    }
}

function setProperty<
    T extends {a: string},
    K extends keyof T
>(o: T, k: K, v: T[K]) {
    o[k] = v
    console.log(o.a)
}

All the classic solutions I can think of lead more or less to v typed as T & Record<'count', number>, which doesn't make setProperty(v, 'count', 1) a valid call because T may have a more precise type than number for the count key.
Playground

I'm not sure to understand the underlying problem you're trying to solve. If your type T may have an optional count property, why not simply define it as such: T extends {a: string, count?: number}?

In my real world problem, interface Entity {a: string} is a type defined in another package. I tried extends Entity & { count?: number } but it's has the same issue.

What exactly are you trying to do? When you say count could be narrower than number, how will that affect your implementation? I'm referring to runtime behavior, not types.

Also do you plan to check the narrower count at runtime, through the number itself? Or through a different property the descriminates its type?

count narrower than number wouldn't have any impact on the runtime, I just need to call the function setProperty with no error, and typesafe if possible

no count is not bounded at runtime

"but it's has the same issue": which issue? If you're talking about setProperty, it's unnecessarily overly specific. setProperty<T, K extends keyof T>, or setProperty<T extends Entity, K extends keyof T> if you want to restrict it to your application, does the job just fine.

@Blackhole ah you're right! T extends Entity & {count?: number} removes the error. In my codebase it doesn't work doing that :/ I need to see why. I'm still interested to see if there is a way without modifying T though.

You can cast the type of the passed number to be (T & {count: number})['count'], essentially narrowing it to a type that's yet to be known, but compatible with T.
And, since we know, from the comments on the question, that at runtime we don't need to narrow v.count further than number, we use a type guard to assert that v extends {count: number}.
interface Entity {
    a: string
}

function countIsNumber<T extends Entity>(x: T): x is T & {count: number} {
    return 'count' in x && typeof x.count === 'number';
}

function setProperty<T extends Entity & Record<K, unknown>, K extends keyof T>(o: T, k: K, v: T[K]) {
    o[k] = v
}

function maybeSetCountToOne<T extends Entity>(v: T) {
    type ParamCount = (T & {count: number})['count'];

    if (countIsNumber(v)) {
        v.count = 1 // v.count: number - Thanks to the type gaurd
        setProperty(v, 'count', 1 as ParamCount) // No error, thanks to the type cast
    }
}

Playground
If we want to avoid type casts. We can use another type guard that asserts that the value we're passing is the same type as v['count']:
interface Entity {
    a: string
}

function countIsNumber<T extends Entity>(x: T): x is T & { count: number } {
    return 'count' in x && typeof x.count === 'number';
}

function countFitsObj<V extends { count: unknown }>(x: V, y: unknown): y is V['count'] {
    return typeof y === typeof x.count;
}

function setProperty<T extends Entity & Record<K, unknown>, K extends keyof T>(o: T, k: K, v: T[K]) {
    o[k] = v
}

function maybeSetCountToOne<T extends Entity>(v: T) {
    if (countIsNumber(v)) {
        const newCount = 5;
        if (countFitsObj(v, newCount)) {
            setProperty(v, 'count', newCount) // No error, no typecast
        }
    }
}

Playground

Interesting idea to leverage ParamCount, but in the end any Typescript issue can be solved with a type cast. The question was about if there is a way using narrowing only.

@Exifers I updated the answer with an approach that doesn't rely on type casting.
